# Axios returns promise pending

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, axios

i want this function to return either true or false, instead I get

```
/**
 * Sends request to the backend to check if jwt is valid
 * @returns {boolean} 
 */
const isAuthenticated = () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('jwt'); 
    if(!token) return false; 
    const config = {headers : {'x-auth-token' : token}}; 

    const response = axios.get('http://localhost:8000/user' , config)
    .then(res =>  res.status === 200 ? true : false)
    .catch(err => false);

    return  response;
}   

export default isAuthenticated;
```

I tried separating  them and using async/await :

```
const isAuthenticated = async () => {
    const response = await makeRequest();
    return  response;
}   


const makeRequest = async () => { 
    const token = localStorage.getItem('jwt'); 
    const config = {headers : {'x-auth-token' : token}}; 
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/user' , config)
    .then(res =>  res.status === 200 ? true : false)
    .catch(err => false);

    return response;
}
```

And still the same..

After some suggestions :

```
const isAuthenticated =  () => {
    const response =  makeRequest();
    return  response;
}   


const makeRequest = async () => { 
    try {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('jwt'); 
        const config = {headers : {'x-auth-token' : token}}; 
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/user', config);
        if (response.status === 200) { // response - object, eg { status: 200, message: 'OK' }
            console.log('success stuff');
            return true;
        }
        return false;
   } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return false;
   }
}
export default isAuthenticated;
```

Comment: `await` ~ `then` is a antipattern, you should to check about [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) & [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all if.
If you are using the default promise then & catch, then the success action should be handled within the 'then' function.

```
axios.get('http://localhost:8000/user', config)
.then(res => console.log('succesfull stuff to be done here')
.catch(err => console.error(err)); // promise
```

if you want to use the async/await syntactic sugar, which I personally like it's

```
const makeRequest = async () => { 
    try {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('jwt'); 
    const config = {headers : {'x-auth-token' : token}}; 
    const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/user', config);
    if (response.status === 200) { // response - object, eg { status: 200, message: 'OK' }
      console.log('success stuff');
     return true;
    }
    return false;
   } catch (err) {
     console.error(err)
     return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: it logs out the success stuff but I am interested in that true or false value, it is not returning true or false, but still Pending. I am doing `console.log(makeRequest())` Apologies if this is straight forward and i am just not getting it

Comment: What approach are you going for? promise.then.catch or async/await?

Comment: if you are using promise.then.catch then you can't simply console.log(promise), you will get pending. what you CAN do it, inside of the promise.then() handle the status === 200 there

Comment: Async await, the example you posted. I will update the question with what i've tried so you can see.

Comment: if you do it like this `.then(res =>  res.status === 200 ? true : false)` that means that you returning an boolean `true` or `false`. you can catch that with `.then(res =>  res.status === 200 ? true : false).then(boolValue => {console.log(boolValue)})` you should see now an true or false in the console. i hope that you are familiar with that syntax `(res => someValue)` thats the same like `(res => { return someValue; })`

Comment: I guess issue you are facing, is that you are trying to access a promise outside of an async func, if you really wanna to do that then use 'then' function. Also instead of status === 200 ? true : false, just use status === 200, because it will return either true of false either way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to employ the use of async/await,like this:

```
const isAuthenticated =async () => {
const token = localStorage.getItem('jwt'); 
if(!token) return false; 
const config = {headers : {'x-auth-token' : token}}; 

const response =await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/user' , config)
.then(res =>  res.status === 200 ? true : false)
.catch(err => false);

return  response;
```

}